# Why my embed is changing the style of my page

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, embed

I have my widget on js that I created, is getting /style.css and some /bootstrap.css 
When I embed it on a Website it changes the look or it changes the look of a website.

What should be the case, what should I do so this does not happen?
This is how embed looks like:

```
<script src="https://dev.mywebsite.com/dir/plugins/widget/bdd/bdd_widget.js?0.59014100 1571698088" type="text/javascript"></script><input type="hidden" name="nuvipclb_id" value="160874"><div id="b-widget"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should add the css and script link tag to the website you are adding the code.

- Or if the website that has the embed code on it is secured with https it could not request some of the files from another website for security issues .